# running deserialization with minimal privilege and with signing or encryption

Tags: java, security

We're using java & spring mvc. It is suggested in many places that:

- Run the Deserialization Code with **Limited Access Permissions** Only
- Deserialize **Signed** Data

For running with limited privilege, what I think of is using doPrivilege() method to wrap deserialization code. But many times, spring mvc just does the deserialization for you like create a java object from json input from a web client.
How can we enforce limit privilege for that?

Regarding deserialize signed data. It is also not something we usually do. Any best practice for it?

Thanks!